# How to correct rcorr() warning in R

Tags: r, hmisc

I got the warning message, `In sqrt(1 - h * h) : NaNs produced`, when I run `Hmisc::rcorr()` for a dataset of 36 rows and 16 columns (all numeric). How can I correct this?

Comment: Does it work with `cor`?

Comment: To be able to answer this, you'll probably need to provide a minimum reproducible example - that's a short code including your data that demonstrates the problem. `dput()` is often the best way to get your data into a form that can be posted here.

Comment: Seems like you are taking the square root of negative numbers. Check your `r -h*h`vector.

Comment: rcorr.adjust(x, type="pearson", use="pairwise.complete.obs") #tried this. Error was... could not find function "rcorr.adjust"

Comment: The `rcorr.adjust()` function is in package `RcmdrMisc`. Have you installed the package with `install.packages("RcmdrMisc")` and loaded it with `library(RcmdrMisc)`?